# How do I execute dotnet test in background mode on Linux

Tags: .net-core

I want to launch my test suite from a bash script using the `&` operator in background mode b/c I want my bash script to do something else while the test suite is running.

This doesn't seem possible ATM. What I see is:

```
$ dotnet test --filter "FullyQualifiedName~GenerateTransactions" >> dotnet.log 2>&1 & 
[1] 2068
```

Tailing the log file for 5 minutes doesn't show me anything. Then pressing Enter in the terminal where I started the tests appears to show me that the dotnet process has stopped

```
$ <press Enter>

[1]+  Stopped                 dotnet test --filter "FullyQualifiedName~GenerateTransactions" >> dotnet.log 2>&1
```

Then I type `fg` and the dotnet process comes to the foreground and the log file immediatelly starts filling with output:

```
$ fg
dotnet test --filter "FullyQualifiedName~GenerateTransactions" >> dotnet.log 2>&1
```

So how do I make `dotnet test` detach from the controlling terminal/script ?

Answer (score 1):

you can use `nohup` command to start you `dotnet test`

`nohup dotnet test --filter "FullyQualifiedName~GenerateTransactions" >> dotnet.log &`